# swipeJS - bug using anchor links

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, swipe

I've tried to search Google and read almost all the problems and issues on the Github of SwipeJS but I really can't find any solution to my problem.

**SwipeJS:**

https://github.com/bradbirdsall/Swipe

**Problem:**

I'm trying to use Anchor Links to jump directly to a specific slide in a SwipeJS content Slider. (href="#thirdslide")

This works but the problem is that SwipeJS now sees the new slide as the first slide and the .prev() function doesn't allow me to go back. The .next() function works but keeps going into blank slides.

Does anybody know how I can fix this (easy)?
I'm relatively new to programming with Javascript so please excuse me if it's a dumb question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(function() {
    // when you click the link w/ a class of 'linkage'
    $('.linkage').click(function() {
        // scroll to the DIV w/ an ID of 'three'
        $.scrollTo( '#three', 800, {easing:'swing'} );
        // highlight the DIV using jQuery UI effect
        $('#three').effect('highlight', {}, 3000);
    });
});
```

Gives a error that scrollTto doesn't exists. 
remove and it and use this as a button

```
<a href="#" class="linkage" onclick="slider.slide(3, 100)return false;">Linkage</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im actually having the same problem.

I'm using the same script, and Im trying to link to a specific slide from some anchor links.

is it possible for someone to post a link to a working demo, or a JSFiddle?

Would be greatly appreciated.

My HTML is

```
   <div id="timeline">
            <ul id="dates">
         <li class="on">2000</li>
    <li><a href='#'>2002</a></li>

    </ul>


    <div class="swipe" id="slider">
        <ul class="swipe-wrap" id="issues">
            <li class="slide1" id="2000">
                <h1>2000</h1>

                <p>Donec semper quam scelerisque tortor dictum gravida. In
                hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam pulvinar, odio sed
                rhoncus suscipit, sem diam ultrices mauris, eu consequat
                purus metus eu velit. Proin metus odio, aliquam eget
                molestie nec, gravida ut sapien. Phasellus quis est sed
                turpis sollicitudin venenatis sed eu odio. Praesent eget
                neque eu eros interdum malesuada non vel leo. Sed fringilla
                porta ligula.</p>
            </li>

            <li class="slide2" id="2002">
                <h1>2002</h1>

                <p>Donec semper quam scelerisque tortor dictum gravida. In
                hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam pulvinar, odio sed
                rhoncus suscipit, sem diam ultrices mauris, eu consequat
                purus metus eu velit. Proin metus odio, aliquam eget
                molestie nec, gravida ut sapien. Phasellus quis est sed
                turpis sollicitudin venenatis sed eu odio. Praesent eget
                neque eu eros interdum malesuada non vel leo. Sed fringilla
                porta ligula.</p>
            </li>

            <li id="three">
                <h1>2005</h1>

                <p>Donec semper quam scelerisque tortor dictum gravida. In
                hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam pulvinar, odio sed
                rhoncus suscipit, sem diam ultrices mauris, eu consequat
                purus metus eu velit. Proin metus odio, aliquam eget
                molestie nec, gravida ut sapien. Phasellus quis est sed
                turpis sollicitudin venenatis sed eu odio. Praesent eget
                neque eu eros interdum malesuada non vel leo. Sed fringilla
                porta ligula.</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I had a silly typo on the onclick event.  works like a charm.

```
      <li><a href="#" onclick='slider.slide(1,300);return false;'>2002</a></li>
```